# Error Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: en Android

Tags: java, android

A veces me aparece el siguiente error

> Performing stop of activity that is not resumed:

Tengo `MainActivity` que en el `onCreate` hace una comprobación si es la primera vez que el usuario abre la app para abrir otra actividad de bienvenida `OnBoarding` y es cuando pulsa retroceso o botón saltar, cuando aparece el error.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OnBoardingActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
...
}
```

Me parece que el error es que a veces no dejo tiempo que `MainActivity` se guarde en el stack de la pila y al llamar inmediatamente otra actividad, cuando quiere volver atrás no hay referencia de nada.

Comment: posible solución es ponerlo en onResumen la llamada, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947675/android-4-4-2-java-lang-runtimeexception-performing-stop-of-activity-that-is/23246159#23246159

Comment: hola amigo como curiosidad en que método haces la comprobación y el intent?

Comment: Muy buenas  y felices fiestas, en el onCreate de la MainActivity es donde llamo la onBoarding y ahora estoy realizando pruebas en ponerlo en onResume, no me da error, pero jejejej evidentemente me está causando un loop, estoy en llena batalla con la libreria Once

Comment: igualmente @Webserveis, veo entonces que el problema es realizar el intent cuando regresa la aplicación (ejecuta onResume()).

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de esta respuesta en [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947675/android-4-4-2-java-lang-runtimeexception-performing-stop-of-activity-that-is/23246159#23246159)
He solventado el Error o eso me parece, ya que era muy arbitrario.
Para llamar la actividad lo puesto en `onResumen` pero evidentemente esto crea un loop de cuando sales de la otra actividad y vuelves a la general.

Usando la [libreria Once](https://github.com/jonfinerty/Once) se puede evitar:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OnBoardingActivity.class);
    if (!Once.beenDone(Constants.COMPLETE_ONBOARDING)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "NO COMPLETE ONBOARDING ");
        if (!Once.beenDone(Once.THIS_APP_INSTALL,Constants.SHOW_ONBOARDING)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "NEED SHOW ONBOARDING");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Como otra opción podría ser guardar el estado en una preferencia para evitar llamar el intent nuevamente al llamarse onResume(), saludos.